# Hello, how i can create a curved shape app bar in flutter as per image?

Tags: flutter

return **strong text**Scaffold(

appbar: AppBar(
leading: InkWell(
child: SvgPicture.asset(
'assets/arrow.svg',
),
onTap: () {
Navigator.pop(context);
},
));

Comment: can you explain briefly what kind of cured appBar you need

Comment: yes i can upload image here you see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJt9D.png

Comment: you can refer here: https://protocoderspoint.com/flutter-custom-appbar-curved-bottom-shape-appbar/

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarOnly extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarOnly({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            // backgroundImage: AssetImage(''),
            radius: 60,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
              child: Text(
                'Logo Here',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NB: Change the background color of the app bar to meet your need

[image: Check this image]

Comment: you have done 90% work but my original appbar is this

Comment: Have you done it then?

Comment: your code is working fine but when I am putting  image then image was cut 50%.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final double topWidgetHeight = 200.0;
  final double avatarRadius = 50.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                height: topWidgetHeight,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
          new Positioned(
            child: new CircleAvatar(
              radius: avatarRadius,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ),
            left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2) - avatarRadius,
            top: topWidgetHeight - avatarRadius,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```